# Intercept network packets in iOS

Tags: ios, networking

Is it possible to intercept and record network packets in an iOS application? If so, what type of application would this be and which platform/language allows it?

Comment: Are you going this for debugging purposes or as part of the app functionality?

Comment: As part of the functionality. I am aware of the private API solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Apple will not allow that level of device access on public apps. It would open giant privacy holes for any user of the device. Imagine a Google app being able to sniff the traffic for any other app on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is something to do with Packet Capture.

There's an open source project found at https://code.google.com/p/pcap-touch-server

There's also a [separate & distinct libpcap library](http://www.tcpdump.org) which can be built for iOS [using this GitHub project](https://github.com/D4rkM4t3r/libpcap-iphone).

Comment: Would such an application be distributable via the Apple store?

Comment: [PCapTouch is available on the Apple app store](http://pcaptouch.net) so Apple *appears* to allow this, but who knows exactly what the current review guidelines truly are.

Comment: PCapTouch requires an external server to actually do the capturing. PCapTouch just displays the capture files obtained on other systems. It doesn't appear to actually capture on the device.